# Twilio Phone call send Media Event

Tags: python, twilio, twilio-api

I am stuck at an Twilio Project in Python:
I want to send an media_response inside of an activ stream. This media response should be an Text to Speach. I choose the Python Libary gTTTS to generate audio. Everytime I am testing, twilio plays absolutly nothing and I do not know why...

here is my code:

```
speak = 'Hallo Welt'
tts = gTTS(text=speak, lang='de')

# Save the TTS audio to a temporary file
temp_file = 'temp_audio.wav'
tts.save(temp_file)

# Read the content of the temporary file to get the audio data
with open(temp_file, 'rb') as f:
    audio_data = f.read()

os.remove(temp_file)  # Remove the temporary file

audio_data = audioop.ratecv(audio_data, 2, 1, 16000, 8000, None)[0]
audio_data = audioop.lin2ulaw(audio_data, 2)

payload = base64.b64encode(audio_data).decode('utf-8')


media_response = {
    'event': 'media',
    "streamSid": f'{sid}',
    'media': {
        'payload': payload,
        'type': 'audio/x-mulaw',
    }
}
ws.send(json.dumps(media_response))
```

Does somebody has any Idea what I did wrong or how to send a media event in a twilio phone call?

I tried different encoding types and also removing the sid.